# How to assign "the same" competition place to sorted list elements in case they are equal?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of athletes(name, score, place) with names and scores already set. I need to get their place number in the competition depending on the score.

At the moment I keep them in a `TreeSet`, so they are already sorted in ascending order. If all the scores are different, I can just do this:

```
    int place=1;        
    for (Athlete athlete:allAthletes){
        athlete.setRelativePlace(place++);
    }
```

The problem is, if two athletes have the same score, they have to have something like "1-2" or "8-9-10" as assigned places. E.g. the winners both got 8000 points, they both should have a String "1-2" in their place field. The next person - if her score is unique - will get the normal "3", etc.
Is there a way to this in a few simple lines without having to do two loops and adding extra fields in Athlete class?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but it is not too difficult to generate the ranks you want in a single pass over all athletes.  Rather than using `8-9-10` as a rank label I would recommend just using `8` for all three athletes.  That is, there are three athletes tied for 8th place.

```
int rank = 0;
int score = -1;

for (Athlete a : allAthletes) {
    int currScore = a.getScore();
    if (currScore != score) {
        ++rank;
        score = currScore;
    }
    a.setRelativePlace(rank);
}
```

This ranking system is what is referred to as the "dense rank" in database jargon.  Using this scheme, if there were two athletes tied for first place, and three tied for third place, we would have the following ranks:

```
score | dense rank
100   | 1
100   | 1
95    | 2
80    | 3
80    | 3
80    | 3
```

**Edit:** Assuming you are stuck with your requirement, then consider the following script.  Rather than relying on your class, which I can't test unless I guess what your code looks like, I just print rankings on a sorted list of scores, in ascending order.

```
List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();
scores.add(80);
scores.add(80);
scores.add(80);
scores.add(90);
scores.add(100);
scores.add(100);
Collections.sort(scores);

int pos = 0;
int score = -1;
int prevScore = -1;
int a = 0;

for (int currScore : scores) {
    System.out.println("DEBUG: current score is: " + currScore);
    if (score == -1) {
        score = currScore;
        prevScore = currScore;
        ++a;
        continue;
    }
    if (score != currScore || a == scores.size() - 1) {
        String rank = "";
        prevScore = score;
        // this covers the case of the last score, or group of scores
        if (a == scores.size() - 1) ++a;
        for (int i=0; i < a - pos; ++i) {
            if (i > 0) rank += "-";
            rank += (pos + i + 1);
        }
        for (int i=pos; i < a; ++i) {
            System.out.println("Score " + prevScore + " has rank " + rank);
        }
        score = currScore;
        pos = a;
    }
    ++a;
}

Score 80 has rank 1-2-3
Score 80 has rank 1-2-3
Score 80 has rank 1-2-3
Score 90 has rank 4
Score 100 has rank 5-6
Score 100 has rank 5-6
```

Follow the link below for a running demo of the above code snippet.

### Demo

Comment: Yes, I would quite prefer to do that. Unfortunately, this "8-9-10" is part of the assignment, so I kinda don't have a choice :)

Comment: @ElenaHeinsalu I could post a solution for that as well, but it would take me at least 20-30 minutes with testing, and then you wouldn't learn anything.  At least this answer sets you in the right direction.

Comment: I guess if it takes 30 minutes, the answer to "Is there a way to this in a few simple lines?" is more like "No":) But yeah, I can do it myself, probably won't be very pretty, but will work:) Thank you!

Comment: @ElenaHeinsalu I solved your problem, it only took 45 minutes.  I gave you a general solution which should easily be able to adapt to your actual code.  If not, then you should really consider learning some more Java.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I keep them in a TreeSet, so they are already sorted in ascending order. **TreeSet wont keep two Athletes having same score if you compare Athletes score while storing in TreeSet.**

Assuming relativePlace is of int type.Its better to Store Athletes in List and sort them with Comparator. Athletes with same score will be listed in the insertion order.

```
 public class Athlete {

     private String name;
     private int score;
     private int relativePlce;
 }
```

Sorting will be like..

```
athletes.sort((o1, o2) -> new Integer(o1.getScore()).compareTo(o2.getScore()));
    int place = 1;
    for (Athlete athlete : athletes) {
        athlete.setPlcae(place++);
        System.out.println( athlete.getName()+":"+athlete.getScore() + ":" + athlete.getPlcae());
```

Answer (score 0):

As one now merely has a `setRelativePlace(int)`, one could store the starting place:

```
int priorScore = -1;
int priorPlace = -1;
int place = 0;        
for (Athlete athlete: allAthletes) {
    int score = athlete.getScore();
    ++place;
    if (score != priorScore) {
        priorScore = score;
        priorPlace = place;
    }
    athlete.setRelativePlace(priorPlace);
}
```

Having a data structure for a range of places one could patch the last found place:

```
static class Place {
    int start;
    int end; // inclusive

    @Override
    String toString() {
        if (start == end) {
            return Integer.toString(start);
        }
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)
            .map(Integer::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("-"));
    }
}

int priorScore = -1;
Place priorPlace = null;
int place = 0;        
for (Athlete athlete: allAthletes) {
    int score = athlete.getScore();
    ++place;
    if (score != priorScore) {
        priorScore = score;
        priorPlace = new Place();
        priorPlace.start = place;
    }
    priorPlace.end = place;
    athlete.setRelativePlace(priorPlace);
}
```

When allAthletes would be a sorted List and you have two int fields start and end:

```
int priorScore = -1;
int priorPlace = -1;
for (int place = 0; ; ++place) {
    if (place == allAthletes.size() || allAthletes.get(place)) {
        for (int p = priorPlace; p < place; ++p) {
            allAthletes.setTillPlace(place - 1);
        }
    }
    if (place == allAthlets.size()) {
        break;
    }
    int score = athlete.getScore();
    if (score != lastScore) {
        priorScore = score;
        priorPlace = place;
    }
    athlete.setRelativePlace(priorPlace);
}
```